# Копирование файлов с рандомным именем на конце

Tags: c#

У меня есть список файлов собранные в `List<string>` Имена без расширения.

Есть папка куда я хочу скопировать один и тот же файл, но только добавив каждому файлу рандомный номер:

пример:

`ListFiles - Это List<string> ( здесь собранные файлы )`

```
Random s = new Random();
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(PathForCreate, "NameFolder"));
for (int i = 0; i < ListFiles.Count; i++)
{
    File.Copy(ListFiles[i], Path.Combine(PathForCreate, "NameFolder"), 
    Path.GetFileName(ListFiles[i]) + s.Next(50)),false);
}
```

Мне пишет что: **такой файл уже существует.**

В новой папке должно быть что-то типо такого:

\NameFolder\

Database

Database12

Database30

и.т.д - То есть рандомные числа на конце, и чтобы они небыли одинаковы.

Comment: Ну а `File.Exist` почему не используете? Или, лучше, просто запоминайте все сгенерированные числа и проверяйте при генерации следующего, что он не повторяется

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Как это проверить?

Comment: `int r; do { r = s.Next(50); } while (!myHashSet.Add(r));` - на выходе имеем неповторяющиеся r. Здесь `myHashSet = new HashSet<int>();`

Comment: @АндрейNOP при наличии 50 копий файла, у вас получится бесконечный цикл. Стоит хотя бы бросать исключение. Но при большом количестве дубликатов на столь малом диапазоне, вы будете совершать очень много холостых операций в попытках сгенерировать недостающие элементы с шансом 1 к 49.

Comment: @LunarWhisper, ну да, но это и не ответ, а всего лишь подсказка автору, которую, конечно, надо будет дорабатывать

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере вначале генерируется список из 50 элементов со значениями от 0 до 49, после чего из него достаются случайные значения. Если файл уже существует, мы берём следующее, и так, пока не исчерпаем все доступные.

Если производительность критична, то вместо `List<Int32>` стоит реализовать другую коллекцию, с возможность быстрого удаления элементов.

При высокой вероятности коллизии и небольшим диапазоном доступных значений, мне кажется, что это оптимальное решение.

Если диапазон будет шире, то эффективнее использовать `HashSet` и запоминать уже сгенерированные номера, а так же те, на которых мы получили ошибку - файл уже существует.

Если в качестве целевой папки использовать %temp%, то лучше подойдёт стандартный метод `Path.GetTempFileName`.

Наконец, если читабельность имён не критична, я бы вообще заменил рандомный хвост на `Guid.NewGuid()`, который гарантирует вам уникальность за счёт стремящейся к нулю вероятности коллизии.

```
    RandomNumbers random = new RandomNumbers(maxValue: 50);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(PathForCreate, "NameFolder"));
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < ListFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        String sourceFileName = ListFiles[i];
        String destFileName = Path.Combine(PathForCreate, "NameFolder", Path.GetFileName(ListFiles[i]));

        CopyFileWithRandomName(random, destFileName, sourceFileName);
    }


private static void CopyFileWithRandomName(RandomNumbers random, String destFileName, String sourceFileName)
{
    using (IEnumerator<Int32> randomEnumerator = random.EnumerateUniqueValues().GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (randomEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            try
            {
                destFileName += randomEnumerator.Current;
                File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName, false);
                return;
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                const Int32 alreadyExistsErrorCode = -2147024816;
                if (ex.HResult != alreadyExistsErrorCode)
                    throw;
            }
        }

        throw new EndOfStreamException("Все доступные номера заняты.");
    }
}

private sealed class RandomNumbers
{
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();
    private readonly List<Int32> _numbers;

    public RandomNumbers(Int32 maxValue)
    {
        List<Int32> numbers = new List<Int32>(maxValue);
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < maxValue; i++)
            numbers.Add(i);
        _numbers = numbers;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Int32> EnumerateUniqueValues()
    {
        Int32 randomIndex = _random.Next(_numbers.Count);
        yield return _numbers[randomIndex];

        List<Int32> tempList = _numbers.ToList();
        tempList.RemoveAt(randomIndex);

        while (tempList.Count > 0)
        {
            randomIndex = _random.Next(_numbers.Count);
            yield return tempList[randomIndex];
            tempList.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
        }
    }
}
```